# Add 1s delay to end of Polly MP3 Conversion

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I'm using Polly to generate text-to-speech MP3 files. I want to add a 1-second pause to the end of each file. How would I do that?

Here's what I'm working with:

```
// Load the SDK
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const Fs = require('fs')
AWS.config.loadFromPath('config.json');

// Create an Polly client
const Polly = new AWS.Polly({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'us-east-1'
})

let params = {
    'Text': "This is the string I'm converting to MP3" ,
    'OutputFormat': 'mp3',
    'VoiceId': 'Kimberly'
}

Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.code)
    } else if (data) {
        if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
            Fs.writeFile("./myverse.mp3", data.AudioStream, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                console.log("The file was saved!")
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add the `'TextType': 'ssml'` parameter. Also, the entire string needs to be enclosed in the `<speak></speak>` tags, with the pause coming between those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [**break section**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supported-ssml.html#break-tag) on [SSML Tags in Amazon Polly documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supported-ssml.html).

```
let params = {
    'Text': `
        This is the string I'm converting to MP3
        <break strength="medium"></break>
    ` ,
    'OutputFormat': 'mp3',
    'VoiceId': 'Kimberly'
};
```

**EDIT**

Maybe you also have to include all your text in a `<speak>` tag ?

Documentation says :

> The `<speak>` tag is the root element of all Amazon Polly SSML text. All
>   SSML-enhanced text to be spoken must be included within this tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that, by Polly actually verbalizes "break strength equals medium...".

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Polly interface also offers SSML - as well as plain text 
(and C# and API support and CLI.) 
The easiest way is to type into the SSML window, here:

**A 1.7 second delay example:**
`<speak>This is the first episode in the MP3 AWS Architect. exam series. <break time="1.7s"/> EC two, exam tips, Part 1.</speak>`

**Five-second gap example (rounded) works equally well:**
`<speak>This is the second episode in the MP3 AWS Architect. exam series. <break time="5s"/> EC two, exam tips, Part 2.</speak>`